# ReentrantLock: Lock/Unlock speed in single-threaded application

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, locking, reentrancy

i'm using some ReentrantLock to synchronize access to a List across multiple threads. I just write a generic

```
try {
   lock.lock();
   ... modify list here
} finally {
   lock.unlock();
}
```

everywhere. I just noticed though, that most of lists across the code are going to be used by a single (gui dispatch-) thread only.

Now i'm not sure if i should remove the lock in these cases, as it might speed up my code.
How fast is ReentrantLock? Is the lock() operation somehow faster if the thread himself was the "prior owner" of the lock, even if he unlock() it?

Comment: Why don't you remove it and measure the performance difference?  Anything else is just guesswork.

Comment: @skaffman: because i heard that micro benchmarks are easily done wrong.

Comment: I don't mean doing micro-benchmarks. I mean using the application for real, or under high load. If you can't tell the difference, then that answers your question.

Comment: @sll, ReentrantLock is basically the same in all java versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No matter how fast it is, it would certainly be slower than no locking, if just by a very small amount. I would personally prefer correctness over speed gain (which won't be a lot) and keep the code the way it is (especially if it is already tested) unless you have identified "locking" to be a bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

3 things:

- lock.lock() should be outside the `try` block.
- if you run on a single core CPU locking is very cheap. Then depending on the CPU architecture the acquire/release might be cheap or not so much. Nehalem+ is sorta ok.
- if you do not need locks for anything else `synchronized` could be a better approach as the JVM can coarsen the monitors and/or bias lock() 'em in a single threaded application. Again the performance of biased locks greatly varies on the CPU architecture.

Comment: Why should lock() be outside the try block?

Comment: @FabianZeindl, b/c if it fails w/ an exception, you're to execute unlock() which will also fail w/ `IllegalMonitorStateException` (or the likes). In the end you get a weird `IllegalMonitorStateException` out of nowhere losing the original cause. The same holds true for anything that needs to be released, it must be obtained 1st.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no contention, acquiring and releasing locks is quite inexpensive. I'd say you needn't worry about the performance implications.

Comment: *acquiring and releasing locks is quite inexpensive.* true but/and not so much, it depends on the CPU architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand if your application is single- or multi-threaded. The title says one thing, and from the body we can infer another thing. I assume that you are using more than one thread (otherwise, the question makes no sense -- why would you use synchronization between ... less than 2 threads?!).

There might be a bigger issue than performance. **Visibility**.

You don't give any details about the part of the code in which you `...modify a list...`, however it is very important to know the details: depending on how you've done that, if you remove the locking what might happen is: one thread modifies the list and the other thread nevers sees these modifications (or sees partial, most probably inconsistent modifications).

The aspect of synchronization that it seems that you are missing is that, unless using some specific constructs (locks / volatile variables / final fields), there are no guarantees that one thread will see what another thread did to the memory.

In this case, your guarantee is given by the locks: when a thread T1 acquires a lock L, it is guaranteed that it will see all the modifications made to the memory by a thread T2 before T2 released the lock L.

```
   T2            T1
acquires L
modifies a
modifies b
releases L
modifies c    acquires L
              reads a
              reads b
              reads c
              releases L
```

In this case, it is guaranteed that T1 will see the correct values for `a` and `b`, but there's no guarantee about what it will see when reading `c`.

If you take out your locks, be sure that your data structure is thread-safe and, if the data contained (ie, your objects inside the list) is not thread-safe, be sure that between each modification and subsequent retrieval of data you trigger a *happens-before* relation, otherwise bad things will happen.

Comment: I use multiple threads but at this they don't share data. I do the work with the various lists in one thread only.

Comment: @FabienZindl, don't you ever touch these lists from other threads? If this is the case, then you don't need any synchronization at all (related to accessing the lists).

Comment: I know. Now i don't. But i might want to change that at some point in the future. Hence the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the test code which shows me that the ReentrantLock is 10 times slower than synchronized on a single thread.

Since my decoder of a custom TCP protocol spends spends 300 ns the speed of locking matters.

JDK 14:

- ReentrantLock: 32.34 ns
- synchronized: 3.48 ns

JDK 11:

- ReentrantLock: 30.3 ns
- synchronized: 3.7 ns

My test:

```
public class MyTest
{
    private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private String s;

    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100_000_000; i++) {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                //
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
        long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long d1 = t2 - t1;
        System.out.println("ReentrantLock: " + d1 / 100f + " ns");

        t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100_000_000; i++) {
            m1();
        }
        t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long d2 = t2 - t1;
        t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100_000_000; i++) {
            m2();
        }
        t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long d3 = t2 - t1;
        long d4 = d2 - d3;
        System.out.println("synchronized: " + d4 / 100f + " ns");
    }

    public synchronized void m1() {
        s = "1";
        s = "2";
        s = "3";
    }

    public void m2() {
        s = "1";
        s = "2";
        s = "3";
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot compare it like this, because the actual values depend on the number of thread amongst other things: http://lycog.com/concurency/performance-reentrantlock-synchronized/
The various JVM implementation can also do optimizations you can't easily measure.

Comment: JVM is not able to optimize ReentrantLocks because these are only Java implementations. You can write your own objective locks as well. The "synchronized" is nothing but monitorenter/monitorexit as two JVM instructions and they can be easily optimized.

Comment: Here in my example i was talking about a single Thread. The question is "why this guy is using the locks in one thread". The answer is that my implementation is polymorphic. And in one situation the application runs with one thread. In another configuration there the user can set many threads.

Comment: 30 nano seconds is really nothing.
The worst times are when the Thread T1 is notified by another Thread T2 and the T1 has to wake up. There we are talking about micro seconds. And that's the worst time.